# dificuldade com a logica while

Tags: c#

Boa tarde, estou tentando fazer um bloco de notas, nele apresento um índice que, ao clicar numero '1' ele redireciona para uma tela onde é preciso colocar o nome que você deseja salvar o arquivo, estou usando o while mas para a re-verificação não da certo, ele retorna que o nome está disponível mesmo já contendo o arquivo na pasta.

Código inteiro da classe Ler Escolha Usuario

namespace BlocoDeNotas
{
internal class LerEscolhaUsuario
{
string nomeArquivo = null;

```
    public void EscolhaMenu()
    {

        Console.Write("Escolha um numero de 1 a 3 do Indice: ");
        bool eUmNumero = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int escolhaIndice);

        while (!eUmNumero)
        {
            Console.Write("Escolha um numero de 1 a 3 do Indice: ");
            eUmNumero = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out escolhaIndice);
        }


        switch (escolhaIndice)
        {
            case 1:

                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("Digite o nome do seu arquivo:");
                nomeArquivo = Console.ReadLine();
                //Verifica se o arquivo existe na pasta
                VerificaArquivo();
                Console.WriteLine("Digite seu texto aqui:");
                string escritaUsuario = Console.ReadLine();
                ReceberEscritaUsuario(escritaUsuario);
                break;

            case 2:
                Console.Clear();
                break;

            case 3:
                Environment.Exit(0);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void VerificaArquivo()
    {
        string arquivo = @"C:\Users\Breno\source\repos\BlocoDeNotas\" + nomeArquivo;

        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(arquivo);
        if (!file.Exists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nome disponível ");
            return;
        }
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            while (file.Exists)
            {
                Console.Write("Este nome de arquivo já existe, digite outro nome: ");
                nomeArquivo = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    private void ReceberEscritaUsuario(string escritaUsuario)
    {
        string saidaTexto = @"C:\Users\Breno\source\repos\BlocoDeNotas\" + nomeArquivo;

        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(saidaTexto))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(escritaUsuario);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Um erro ocorreu!" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

tela inicial, digitando 1 vai para a tela da segunda foto[Foto1 tela inicial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPOO5.jpg)

este codigo:[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orLea.jpg)

imprime isto[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDUtV.jpg)
na primeira linha digito o nome duplicado, ele acusa já ter um arquivo com este nome no diretório, na segunda linha digito denovo o nome duplicado ele libera para a área de digitação do conteúdo más, era para reimprimir a tela pois o nome continua duplicado.

este código:[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Artle.jpg)

imprime isto:[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L65GA.jpg)
na primeira linha digito o nome dúplicado, ele acusa na segunda e na terceira linhas, na quarta e quinta linhas seríam nomes disponíveis mas ele continua acusando como indisponíveis.

Comment: Fiquei curioso, nesse trecho `while (file.Exists)`, ele não entra num loop infinito?

Comment: Entra sim, fica imprimindo: Console.Write("Este nome de arquivo já existe, digite outro nome: "); como mostrado na foto, é esse o problema que quero resolver. :)

Comment: voce precisa repetir a verificacao de existencia de arquivo. Envolva todo o seu método VerificaArquivo em um while(true) e remova aquele if (file.Exists) e while(file.Exists)

Comment: private void VerificaArquivo()
{
    while (true)
    {
        string arquivo = @"C:\Users\Breno\source\repos\BlocoDeNotas\" + nomeArquivo;

        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(arquivo);


        Console.Write("Este nome de arquivo já existe, digite outro nome: ");
        nomeArquivo = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
Quando eu faço essa instrução ele entra em um loop infinito novamente, preciso fazer a verificação do fileinfo file e ele não é acessivel por ninguem neste modo que mencionou

Comment: consegui

bastava adicionar a linha string arquivo e a linha fileinfo no while

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.